# XmlPullParser.getText() return null or "" in this situation?

Tags: xmlpullparser, android-xmlpullparser

The XML file is:

```
<name></name>
```

If I parse the XML with:

```
String result = null;
if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
     result = parser.getText();
     parser.nextTag();
}
return result;
```

Does it return null or does it return an empty string `""` ?

Comment: I haven't tested but I would think it would return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Android Developers XmlPullParser Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#next%28%29)

> If element content is empty (content is "") then no TEXT event will be reported.

So it should return null.